# Discord.js - Is there a method for discord bots to recursively ask questions? Like a form filler bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've written some code down below. My main experience coding is with Python, but I got hooked on a discord.js tutorial and decided to give discord bot coding a try (I know that there's a Python option, but I've already invested a lot of time into this, so unless if it's not feasible, then I will most likely not switch over). I'm still taking a while to get the concept of async/await, hopefully I've applied it correctly in the code. It currently works just asking one question, but I can't seem to continue the operation, even though the counter seems to add fine. I was thinking of a recursive solution, but whenever I do a `while` loop or a recursion function it still starts on the first question again either way. My main concerns would be whether or not I'm going in a path that can get me to ask multiple questions.

---

tl;dr: The code I've written down below allows the bot to record one response, but when I try to make it repeat using a continuous recursive function, the code just starts back at question 1.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';

client.login(token);

const quiz = require('./q.json');
var num = 0;
var item = quiz[num];
var messg = "";
//var line = []; ignore this, this is for recording the responses onto a different application later

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content === '!test') {
        collec(message);
    }
})

async function collec(message) {
    message.reply(item.question);
    //checks to see if the author that used commmand is the same + if it's an option
    //isPossibleOption() = just constantly gets rid of one element until it fits w/ criteria
    const filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id && isPossibleOption(m.content, item.answers);

        var collector = new Discord.MessageCollector(message.channel, filter, { max: 1 });

        collector.on("collect", async msg => {
            messg = msg.content;
            //await recordAnswer(messg, num); record it onto google sheets / check for q
            message.channel.send('Next question!');
            nextQ();
        })

        collector.on("end", collected => {});
}

async function isPossibleOption (message, file) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
        if (message.toLowerCase() == file[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function nextQ () {
    num++;
    item = quiz[num];
}
```

Comment: the `Discord.MessageCollector` is set to collect a `max` of 1 message, so it will stop after one message is received. I'm confused, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? what is the purpose of the Message Collector

Comment: it also seems like `num` is incremented twice, once by `nextQ()` and again right below that. what's the purpose of that.

Comment: My plan for the message collector is to ask one question, get one answer, and then ask a different question, and then collect the answer.

Comment: As for ```num```, I don't know. I think I might've added that by accident and forgot to take it out.

Comment: so where exactly is the problem? what happens when the bot is running.

Comment: The bot is only able to record one question and one response, that's it. However, I want to make a recursive or an iteration that makes it able to ask the next question in ```quiz```, which is the file that has the different questions.

Comment: I just tested it. It's seems to be working for me. remove all that `async` stuff. It's unnecessary

Comment: I know it works for one question, but when I try to put multiple ```collec(message)``` after the ```if (message.content === !'test')``` statement, it just runs the functions simultaneously. I'm trying to find a way to solve that. Sorry for the previously crappy explanations.

Comment: what you want is to have multiple `collec(message)`'s in the `if(message.content == '!test')` branch. is that what you are saying. send me you discord username so we can talk through discord it would be easier.

Comment: Yes, that was my original plan. Is there any way I could DM my discord username to you?

Comment: Okay, I've just sent you a friend request.

Comment: I've added you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [discord.js guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-collector) actually provides a good answer to this. There's an implemented message collector that you can start and end once you've finished collecting.

Basic implementation of code (seen on website):

```
// `m` is a message object that will be passed through the filter function
const filter = m => m.content.includes('discord');
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

collector.on('collect', m => {
    console.log(`Collected ${m.content}`);
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

It allows for many different parameters, such as a time limit of how long you can respond, how many messages the messageCollector will collect, etc. For setting it up, you'll need to create a `.json` to store your questions as well as answers, refer to the link for more information.